# Array elements behaving unexpectedly

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to learn the Bash syntax. As the documentation I'm reading confirms, I expect ARRAYNAME[0] to access element 1 and ARRAYNAME[1] to access element 2. However,there seems to be something funny happening with my script. Trying to access ARRAYNAME[0] seems to give me an empty string, as I show output in the comments below.
The following script is what I've edited to make the output print as I expect. I don't think my problems come from running `zsh` as I've tried running this script with `/bin/sh`. What am I not seeing here?
Thanks in advance.

Test.sh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
NAMES=(Homer Marge Bart Lisa Maggy)
OUTPUTSTRING="The Simpsons family consists of: "
FAMILY="This list is empty :("
echo "Names[0]: ${NAMES[0]}"           # prints "Names[0]: "
echo "Names[1]: ${NAMES[1]}"           # prints "Names[1]: Homer"
if [ ${#NAMES[@]} -gt 0 ] ; then
    FAMILY="${NAMES[1]}"
else                                   # does not go in to else
    echo "$OUTPUTSTRING""$FAMILY" 
    exit 0
fi
NAMECOUNTER=2
while [ $NAMECOUNTER -le ${#NAMES[@]} ]; do      #-lt if behaviour was as I expected
    FAMILY+=", ${NAMES[$NAMECOUNTER]}"
    NAMECOUNTER=$((NAMECOUNTER+1))
done

echo "The Simpsons family consists of: $FAMILY"   # The Simpsons family consists of: Homer, Marge, Bart, Lisa, Maggy
```

Comment: Why would you expect the correct results of a bash script when running in another shell?  Whilst zsh and bash share some similarities they are not exactly the same.  So what happens when you use /bin/bash for the same script?

Comment: `bash` arrays are zero-indexed. `zsh` arrays, however, are 1-indexed, and you are running the script with `zsh`. `/bin/sh` typically does not support arrays, although `bash` appears to do so even when invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Comment: zsh is my default shell for extensions and aesthetic reasons. I don't mind testing for consistency between zsh and bash when I have exhausted whether my logic is the problem. Using /bin/bash for the same script gives the same results.

Comment: @chepner Ah! Is the problem that I'm running /bin/bash through zsh? If so, how can I open /bin/bash properly? Also, please submit an answer and I'll accept it when possible.

Comment: Either change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, or run the script with `bash` explicitly: `bash myscript`.

Comment: @chepner Great! I also didn't understand how the shebang functioned - thought that it was used to declare what terminal I'm using, so your comment lead me to read about shebangs. Again, please submit an answer and I'll accept when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing a `bash` script (which expects arrays to be indexed starting from 0) with `zsh` (which indexes arrays starting from 1). Change the shebang to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(or whatever path is correct) to ensure your script is executed by `bash` when you run the script as an executable. Alternatively, explicitly run `myscript` with `bash` using `bash myscript` instead of, e.g., `./myscript`.